# MySQL connection works on CLI, but not on Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

> Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug) 3.19.3-100.fc20.x86_64
>
> Packages:
>
> - mysql-workbench-community.x86_64      6.1.7-1.fc20
> - mariadb.x86_64                        1:5.5.41-1.fc20
> - mariadb-libs.x86_64                   1:5.5.41-1.fc20
> - mariadb-server.x86_64                 1:5.5.41-1.fc20

I can connect to a running, remote MySQL database server just fine using the command line. I need to

1. remotely login on a remote machine using SSH, and from there
2. perform the MySQL login command.

(Meaning the database server is not on my local network and I can not connect to it from my local machine).

```
[user@my-local-machine ~]$ ssh [user]@[remote-host] -p [port]

[user@remote-host ~]$ mysql -u [db-user] -h 192.168.x.x -p
```

> Enter password:
>
> Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your
> MariaDB connection id is [id] Server version: 5.5.40-MariaDB MariaDB
> Server
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
> statement.
>
> MariaDB [(none)]>

---

However, if I try to use MySQL Workbench, I get the following error:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at 192.168.x.x:3306 through SSH tunnel at [host]:[port] with user [db-user]
>
> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a software bug in MySQL Workbench. Upgrading `mysql-workbench-community.x86_64` to version `6.3.3-1.fc20` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I helped him find a workaround in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21281612#21281612):

Evidently his MySQL Workbench app is not able to properly set up the SSH forwarding tunnel, so I had him set it up manually using the OpenSSH `ssh` client as follows:

`ssh -L 33000:192.168.x.x:3306 user@host`

Then, once that is running, he was able to do a direct connect in MySQL Workbench to `localhost:33000` and it worked.

Comment: It works on the GUI, but not on the CLI `mysql` command. And there are features on the GUI that call a CLI backend that runs the `mysql` command, that fails with the same error I see on the CLI :(